# How to delete a row from a SQLite table in Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-sqlite

I want to delete a row from a SQLite table. I have looked at different tutorials, and nothing seems to be working. 
This is my method:

```
public void deleteNote(int id) {

}
```

'id' is a row id. 
This is what calls this method:

```
deleteNote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                DB.deleteNote(id);
            }
        });
```

Also, as a side note, how can I go to a different method once this row is deleted?

Comment: db.delete("table_name", " id = ? " ,new String[]{id});

Answer (score 2):

it would be better if u declare your id as string

you have to create a database handler class. In that class you have to add like the following code.

```
public Integer deleteNote(String id){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(TABLE_NAME,"ID = ?",new String[] {id});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This working code from my app

```
public Integer deleteData (String sub) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "SUBJECT = ?",new String[] {sub});
}
```

you need to add the code like below

```
public Integer deleteData (int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "<----here your column name---> = ?",new String[] {id});
}
```

if any error add that error

Answer (score 1):

This is working code of my Application

```
public void deleteNote(String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
    db.close();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create the method on database handler class. Call it with passing id of the row or something unique.

```
public boolean deleteNote(int id) 
{
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ID + "=" + id, null) > 0;
}
```

Here, `DATABASE_TABLE` is the name of your table. `KEY_ID` is the id colum name of your table.

Comment: This is what I added: 

    public boolean deleteNote(int id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(notes.notesData.noteTableName, notes.notesData._ID + "=" + id, null) > 0;
    }

But it's not working. The app just closes when I press the delete button.